# Plot horizontal lines in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, horizontal-line

I am trying overlay horizontal lines to a candlestick chart using plotly. However, when I am unable to get the horizontal lines to start at the their 'x' coordinate which is found in `df['date'][level[0]]`. Instead the horizontal lines are starting a x=0.

Below is what I have managed to muster together so far, which I imagine is not pretty to an experienced eye.

However any pointers to assist would be much appreciated:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot
import datetime as dt
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



hovertext=[]
for i in range(len(df['bidopen'])):
    hovertext.append('Datetime: '+str(df['date'][i])+'<br>Open: '+str(df['bidopen'][i])+'<br>Close: '+str(df['bidclose'][i]))


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=df['date'],
                open=df['bidopen'],
                high=df['bidhigh'],
                low=df['bidlow'],
                close=df['bidclose'],
                text=hovertext,
                hoverinfo='text'))

for level in levels:
    fig.add_hline(level[1], df['date'][level[0]], exclude_empty_subplots=True)


plot(fig)
```

Here is a screen shot of what my plotly code currently produces (current output):

[image]

Below is what what I am trying to achieve in respect to the horizontal lines (desired output):

[image]

..this second screenshot represents what I was able to produce with matplotlib

Comment: The docs for `add_hline` explicitly say that it will extend infinitely in the x-dimension (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_hline), so I guess you can't use that function. I think you'd have to either draw them as a new scatter plot, or use `add_shape(type="line", ...)`. Relevant docs/examples here: https://plotly.com/python/shapes/

Comment: @alkasm Yes, add_shape seems to be the function best suited. Many thanks

Comment: Out of the question, but can I ask how did you find those support levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `hline()` extends the plots to infinity on both sides, you can use `add_shape()` method.

Considering a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'levels':np.random.random(10)*10, 
                          'dates':pd.date_range(start = '2020-11-01', periods = 10)})
df

    levels  dates
0   9.149079    2020-11-01
1   0.294123    2020-11-02
2   5.401443    2020-11-03
3   4.043063    2020-11-04
4   8.878100    2020-11-05
5   5.275614    2020-11-06
6   4.425696    2020-11-07
7   8.228720    2020-11-08
8   7.632410    2020-11-09
9   7.045191    2020-11-10
```

& a figure already having dates you want as indices:

[image]

You can do something like:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    fig.add_shape(type="line", x0= row[1]['dates'], 
                            y0 = row[1]['levels'],
                            x1 = df.dates.max(),
                            y1 = row[1]['levels'], fillcolor = 'yellow')
fig
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: your add_shape example with a sight tweak did it. My levels were infact produced as tuples, with a row index rather than the actual date. What I done based on your example can now be seen in answer...

Answer (score 3):

Using example from @Hamza please see solution below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(levels, columns = ['dates', 'levels'])

df1.set_index('dates', inplace=True)

for i in df1:
      df1['dates'] = df.date[df.index.isin(df1.index)]

hovertext=[]
for i in range(len(df['bidopen'])):
    hovertext.append('Datetime: '+str(df['date'][i])+'<br>Open: '+str(df['bidopen'][i])+'<br>Close: '+str(df['bidclose'][i]))


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=df['date'],
                open=df['bidopen'],
                high=df['bidhigh'],
                low=df['bidlow'],
                close=df['bidclose'],
                text=hovertext,
                hoverinfo='text'))

for row in df1.iterrows():
    fig.add_shape(type="line", x0= row[1]['dates'], 
                            y0 = row[1]['levels'],
                            x1 = df.date.max(),
                            y1 = row[1]['levels'], fillcolor = 'yellow')

plot(fig)
```